# How do I set "audience or resource" for Ansible module azure.azcollection.azure_rm_networkinterface_info?

Tags: azure, ansible

I am using the `azure.azcollection.azure_rm_networkinterface_info` module in Ansible 2.10.

The play is trivial, just calling the module with no options, to get info on all the interfaces.  The credential file looks like this:

```
[default]
subscription_id=$(ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
client_id=$(ARM_CLIENT_ID)
secret=$(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
tenant=$(ARM_TENANT_ID)
cloud_environment=AzureUSGovernment
```

I don't actually know what those values are, because they are in Azure KeyVault.

The call is returning the following error:

```
Message: The access token has been obtained for wrong audience or resource 
'https://management.azure.com'. It should exactly match with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.usgovcloudapi.net/', https://management.core.usgovcloudapi.net', 'https://management.usgovcloudapi.net/', https://management.usgovcloudapi.net'.",
```

I have no idea how to set that audience or resource.

Update:

The issue only appears in a AzureDevOps pipeline agent.

It works fine on my RHEL8 VM.

Comment: Are these helpful? [Azure PowerShell fails request the correct access token with Managed Identity Service Connection in Azure Government](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-powershell-fails-request-the-correct-access/462525), [USGovernment's Resource Management Endpoint is Wrong](https://github.com/Azure/go-autorest/issues/76) and [Problem when i call a GET REQUEST with an AZURE Token, InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/482868/problem-when-i-call-a-get-request-with-an-azure-to.html)

Comment: [CertificateCredential for AzureUSGovernment cloud](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/24740)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT No, none of those made any difference.  Something options needs to be in that credential file, but I cannot find it. I've tried `resource` and `audience`, but I keep getting exactly the same message.